# What are Selenium Docker image release versions for browser capabilities?

Tags: selenium, docker, docker-compose, dockerhub

Where is a list of all Docker image **release versions** for Selenium browser capabilities?

For instance, I can't find it on the [`standalone-chrome-debug` Docker Hub page](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome-debug/), or in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium). I'm guessing the version numbers should sync with [ChromeDriver versions](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).
`image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:2.27` does not work, and I'd like to lock the version number.

Notice comments at end of images:

```
# docker-compose.yml
...
services:
   selenium:
     image: selenium/standalone-firefox-debug:2.47.1 # works (found this on a blog)
     # image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug # works
     # image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:2.27 # breaks
...
```

Perhaps it's hiding in plain sight. Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

In the [change log of Chromedriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.27/notes.txt) you can see comments like:

```
----------ChromeDriver v2.27 (2016-12-23)----------
Supports Chrome v54-56
```

You can extract it from there though there is no mention of Selenium versions as Chromedriver can be connected directly without the need of a Selenium server nor grid meaning they are independent.

Not sure if will help your case but I kept historical correlation between versions of Selenium, Chromedriver, Chrome, Firefox in the releases page of my project:

https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/releases

Comment: When I use either of the following images, I get an error that the image manifest can not be found:
  image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:v2.24
  image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:2.24
(I used v2.24 here just in case v2.27 was too new and unavailable). 

As a consumer of those images, what is the proper format for the versions?